# Webpack with an array provided as config

Tags: webpack

In this webpack starter kit https://github.com/webpack/react-starter I see the webpack.production.config.js module does not export only a config object but an array of config objects instead:

```
module.exports = [
    require("./make-webpack-config")({
        // commonsChunk: true,
        longTermCaching: true,
        separateStylesheet: true,
        minimize: true
        // devtool: "source-map"
    }),
    require("./make-webpack-config")({
        prerender: true
    })
];
```

What will happen in this case, when multiple config objects are provided? It isn't mentioned in webpack's docs

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Passing an array enables Webpack's multi-compiler mode. It's just a way to run Webpack multiple times in one pass. For instance, if you're making a Chrome & Firefox extension, you could use the multi-compiler to create both at once.

[Webpack Multi-compiler example](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-compiler) using mobile/desktop bundles.

Comment: Does it run in parallel?

Comment: Problem is when you want to run multiple config in watch mode, I was able to achieve this by installing npm package parallel-webpack https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack. @guillaume-cisco might be helpful to you too.

Comment: Parallel watch mode seems to work fine on webpack `4.25.1`. No extra packages required.

Answer (score 1):

Can be used to produce two different outputs - otherwise undoable in Webpack (AFAIK).

Eg: 
Produce full Production-ready output config into wwwroot directory in an ASP.Net Server-side web app, so that you can run and test everything by running the ASP.Net app on IIS, in Visual Studio
WHILE SIMULTANEOUSLY
Produce a simple HTML page (with HtmlWebpackPlugin) into your_app/dist folder, so you can run just the JS app and on Webpack DevServer and edit the JS app, in VSCode

Two people could work side by side on the same project, at the same time, the way John Lennon Imagined...