# How to build a less compilation chain (gulp -style) in Webpack v3?

Tags: css, webpack, gulp, less, webpack-3

For a new project I am bound to keep things webpack-only, and thus need to find a way to efficiently compile our stylesheets. Basically in a very gulh-ish way:

- gather all less-files including [glob-patterns](https://github.com/notagency/webpack2-with-less-plugin-glob) like `src/**/*.less` (css order may be arbitrary)
- also allow import of css files like, say `../node_modules/vendor/**/*.css` or `3rdparty/master.less`

  - (If I have to setup a `bogus.js` entry point for that, fine...)

### And with all of that, a typical gulp workflow:

- transpile less to css
- merge (concat) less and css
- have `cssnano` do its optimization job, with specific css nano options like e.g. `orderedValues: false, normalizeWhitespace: true` ...
- write **`styles.css`** as final output

And of course:

- have source-maps survive that chain for a **`styles.css.map`**
- efficient watching and the usual lazy/incremental compilation (as gulp *and* webpack have it)

Something I do ***not*** need is [`css modules`](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/) (css `imported` into node modules for 'scoped' use, coming out as hash-scoped selectors...)

### How can a 'typical' less|css-processing toolchain be done in Webpack?

This SO question has my [first attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322223/webpack-how-to-merge-css-and-less-then-apply-cssnano) where I got stuck in config hell right in the middle after combining...

---

#### considerations so far (helpful or not)

I know, to webpack, *any* ressource including css or even font and images is a "module"... Rather than merging my css 'modules' with with actual js  (only to later painstakingly separate them again later again), it might be wiser, to have an entry point `cssstub.js` in parallel – also known as [multi-compiler mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29757497/444255).

But that's really, where my wisdom ends... doing a sequence of $things on a set of files in webpack seems really hard (unless it's a connected javascript module graph). I did find [something on globbing](https://github.com/notagency/webpack2-with-less-plugin-glob), but that's not enough (merge css, cssnano,...) and mostly I simply can't glue the pieces together...

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Can you use a Gulp workflow that would use `webpack-stream` ?

Answer (score -2):

I have used gulp to build less and create corresponding maps like below:

First step compiles less and generated css in tmp folder

```
gulp.task('compile-less', function () {
    gulp.src('./*.less') // path to your file
    .pipe(less().on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./tmp/'));
});
```

Second step minifies generated css and create map files

```
gulp.task('build-css', ['clean'], function() {
    return gulp.src('./tmp/**/*.css')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(cachebust.resources())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./compiled/css'));
});
```

If you want you can add additional step to conact generated css.

Comment: requested was a gulp-like workflow in webpack. Not a gulp-like workflow in gulp.